# Pandas: Unable to Classify a Date Column to obtain financial year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a set of dates (sample included as df) which I'm trying to classify into *respective Fiscal Year - for time series analysis; i.e. April 2012-March 2013 & so on*. 
I'm able to do it if i run a FOR loop but its taking me awfully long to do that.
The other option which I thought of doing is to use pd.cut to bin the data which I'm not sure is the best thing to do as I've come across a few queries which indicate that its due to a bug in python which requires the edges to be converted to numeric values

```
x=np.arange('2018-04-02', '2020-04-20',50, dtype= np.datetime64)
df=pd.DataFrame(x)

df["Year"]=""
bin_3=['2018-03-31','2019-03-31','2020-03-31','2021-03-31']
tag=['FY18-19','FY19-20','FY20-21']
df["Year"]=pd.cut(df5["Date of Issue"],bin_3,labels=tag)
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work without sacrificing the processing time?

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: Have you looked at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.qyear.html ?

Comment: @AKX: Just did, doesn't seem to be doing the trick. It's ending up broadcasting the same values for the entire column.

Comment: @MayankPorwal:  Something like this 
```4/2/2018 FY18-19
5/22/2018 FY18-19
7/11/2018 FY18-19
8/30/2018 FY18-19
10/19/2018 FY18-19
12/8/2018 FY18-19
1/27/2019 FY18-19
3/18/2019 FY18-19
5/7/2019 FY19-20
6/26/2019 FY19-20
8/15/2019 FY19-20
10/4/2019 FY19-20
11/23/2019 FY19-20
1/12/2020 FY19-20
3/2/2020 FY19-20```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would use apply here and usually a lambda. But writing a function for clarity.

Assuming you have the dates to be mapped in the "Date" column

```py
def get_fiscal_year(date):
    m = date.month
    yy = date.year % 100
    fy = None

    if m > 3:
        fy = f"FY{yy}-{yy+1}"
    else:
        fy = f"FY{yy-1}-{yy}"

    return fy


df['FiscalYear'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda dt: get_fiscal_year(dt))
```

Comment: @AKX Am I missing something? If the month is greater than 3 (march) then we are in the current fiscal year.